# Simple HTML DOM - Failed to open stream: Connection Timeout

Tags: php, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

Hello I hosted my website into a free hosting site (5gbfree.com) and I created here a function where it retrieves the Peso-dollar rate based from the site http://ppa.com.ph??q=fcer_view where it simply select the `a.active` element and get the value as plaintext. It was working yesterday but when I checked it our again this morning it failed to fetch. So it will return the default value which is 50.

error_log:

```
[09-Apr-2017 13:49:32 Asia/Manila] PHP Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.ppa.com.ph/?q=fcer_view): failed to open stream:     Connection timed out in /home/rasibaseport/public_html/simple_html_dom2.php on line 75
```

I am using simple html DOM.
Here's the function.

```
include "simple_html_dom2.php";

function PPA_peso_dollar_rate(){
// Create DOM from URL or file
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 15);
$html = file_get_html("http://www.ppa.com.ph/?q=fcer_view");
$ret = 0;
if($html === false){
    $ret = 50;
}else {
    foreach($html->find('a[class=active]') as $e) 
    $ret = $e->plaintext;
    $explode = explode(" ", $ret);

    $ret = 50;
    foreach($explode as $ex){
        if(is_numeric($ex)){
            $ret = $ex;
        }
    }
    if($ret == 0) $ret = 50;
}

echo $ret;
}
```

Unfortunately 5gbfree disabled curl_init() function.

```
curl_init() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/rasibaseport/public_html/config.php on line 38
```

Is there any work a round here? I appreciate any help. Thank you very much.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that testing this with localhost(xampp), the expected return value is correct with no errors and warnings. Works perfectly fine.

**UPDATE:** After trying @Rafiq's updated solution, nothing worked. It gave me similar error.

```
[09-Apr-2017 20:18:53 Asia/Manila] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.ppa.com.ph/?q=fcer_view): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/rasibaseport/public_html/simple_html_dom2.php on line 46
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is work for me. Its problem in execution time. Add the following code to increase maximum execution time.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 100); // 100 seconds = 1 Minutes 40 sec
//call the function file_get_html();
```

**Explanation of parameter [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) inside [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) finction**

This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server. **The default setting is 30.** For detail read [Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

**To get rid of the following two error use `fetch_http_file_contents($url)` instead of `file_get_contents($url)`** inside `simple_html_dom.php` on line 75.

> file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: No route to host
>
> file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

```
function fetch_http_file_contents($url) {
  $hostname = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
  if ($hostname == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  $host_has_ipv6 = FALSE;
  $host_has_ipv4 = FALSE;
  $file_response = FALSE;

  $dns_records = dns_get_record($hostname, DNS_AAAA + DNS_A);

  foreach ($dns_records as $dns_record) {
    if (isset($dns_record['type'])) {
      switch ($dns_record['type']) {
        case 'AAAA':
          $host_has_ipv6 = TRUE;
          break;
        case 'A':
          $host_has_ipv4 = TRUE;
          break;
  } } }

  if ($host_has_ipv6 === TRUE) {
    $file_response = file_get_intbound_contents($url, '[0]:0');
  }
  if ($host_has_ipv4 === TRUE && $file_response == FALSE) {
    $file_response = file_get_intbound_contents($url, '0:0');
  }

  return $file_response;
}

function file_get_intbound_contents($url, $bindto_addr_family) {
  $stream_context = stream_context_create(
                      array(
                        'socket' => array(
                          'bindto' => $bindto_addr_family
                        ),
                        'http' => array(
                          'timeout'=>20,
                          'method'=>'GET'
                    ) ) );

  return file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $stream_context);
}
```

Source [Making file_get_contents() more routing-robust and dual-stack](https://ctrl.blog/entry/php-file-contents-dual-stack)

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved my life. Haha. Can you explain or refer me a link explaining what does `ini_set('max_execution_time', seconds);` do? Just a bit curious. Anyway thank you so much :)

Comment: @ghost I added in answer

Comment: Hmmm this is odd. I just tried it now, and it is not working again. Same error logs on error_log

Comment: Increase the value of `default_socket_timeout` default value is 60 but in your code it is 15 which sometimes close the connection if the process not complete within 15 second. So increase time to 60 or 100 in the code `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 15);`

Comment: Unfortunately anything above didn't work, setting `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 60);`,  adding `fetch_http_file_contents($url)` function and replacing `fetch_file_get_contents($url)` in line 75 of simple_html_dom.php. I've updated my post for further details.

Comment: set default time to 100 or more `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 100);` and remove `fetch_http_file_contents`. This work for me